# How to reinitialize vue.js's getter and setter bindings?

Tags: vue.js

Below here i provide a sample code. So what happens here is, i have some objects that i will load from API. The object later will be extended by the UI, in case that some of property that will be used for binding in the UI missing **#app2**. Under normal condition, if all the properties are provided like in **#app1**, the Vue will do the binding recursively to the content of the data object. But currently, in **#app2**, the property is missing and in the UI logic, i add the missing property.

The problem now is, when i added the property that way, the `app2.contentObject.toggleStatus` is not vue's object with getter and setter. how can i manually reinitialize the state of getter and setter so that the changes will be reflected in UI?

```js
var app1 = new Vue({
  el: "#app1",
  data: {
    contentObject: {
      toggleStatus: false
    }
  },
  computed: {
    content: function(){
      var contentObject = this.contentObject;
      return contentObject;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle : function(){
      this.contentObject.toggleStatus  = !this.contentObject.toggleStatus;
    }
  }
})
var app2 = new Vue({
  el: "#app2",
  data: {
    contentObject: {
    
    }
  },
  computed: {
    content: function(){
      var contentObject = this.contentObject;
      contentObject.toggleStatus = false;
      return contentObject;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle : function(){
      this.contentObject.toggleStatus  = !this.contentObject.toggleStatus;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app1">
  current toggle status: {{content.toggleStatus}}<br/>
  <button @click="toggle">Toggle (working)</button>
</div>
<div id="app2">
  current toggle status: {{content.toggleStatus}}<br/>
  <button @click="toggle">Toggle (not working)</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** In `app2` vue instance's case you are trying to add a new property `toggleStatus` and expecting it to be reactive. Vue cannot detect this changes. So you got to initialize the properties upfront as you did in `app1` instance or use `this.$set()` method. See [Reactivity in depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html).

**2.** You are using a computed property. Computed properties should just return a value and should not modify anything. So to add a property `toggleStatus` to `contentObject` make use of created lifecycle hook.

So here are the changes:

```
var app2 = new Vue({
  el: "#app2",
  data: {
    contentObject: {}
  },
  created() {
    this.$set(this.contentObject, "toggleStatus", false);
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function() {
      this.contentObject.toggleStatus = !this.contentObject.toggleStatus;
    }
  }
});
```

Here is the [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2kdsj4qv/)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work in second case first because in your computed property you always assign false to it.

```
contentObject.toggleStatus = false;
```

And secondly you are looking for [Vue.set/Object.assign](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats)

```js
var app1 = new Vue({
  el: "#app1",
  data: {
    contentObject: {
      toggleStatus: false
    }
  },
  computed: {
    content: function(){
      var contentObject = this.contentObject;
      return contentObject;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle : function(){
      this.contentObject.toggleStatus  = !this.contentObject.toggleStatus;
    }
  }
})
var app2 = new Vue({
  el: "#app2",
  data: {
    contentObject: {
    
    }
  },
  computed: {
    content: function(){
      var contentObject = this.contentObject;
      return contentObject;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle : function(){
      this.$set(this.contentObject, 'toggleStatus', !(this.contentObject.toggleStatus || false));
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app1">
  current toggle status: {{content.toggleStatus}}<br/>
  <button @click="toggle">Toggle (working)</button>
</div>
<div id="app2">
  current toggle status: {{content.toggleStatus}}<br/>
  <button @click="toggle">Toggle (not working)</button>
</div>
```